# How to approximate a function by a differentiable function?

Tags: real-analysis

In the picture below, the black graph is of the original function which is not differentiable at the "corner point" $T$, and the red curve is of the expected function which is differentiable on the whole domain.

[image]

My question is how can we construct the function of which graph is the red curve, given the original function?

Thank you very much.

Comment: There are many ways to do this, one way could be to use splines.

Comment: @TonyS.F. Could you explain more specifically, please?

Comment: For this specific case, try $\log(1+\exp(x))$

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with parabolas. Consider $y=|x|$ for example. (This corresponds to a $90$ degree angle at $T.$) The parabola $y=1+x^2/4$ is tangent to $y=|x|$ at the points $(-2,2),(2,2).$ Consider the function that is equal to the parabola on $[-2,2],$ and equal to $|x|$ for $|x|\ge 2.$ That describes a continuously differentiable function that, I think, does what you want.

This is just one example. For any angle at $T$ you are given, you can rotate this figure to be the graph of some $y=m|x|.$ You can then find a family of parabolas of the form $a + bx^2,$ with $a,b>0,$ each of which is tangent to $y=m|x|$ as above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a
hyperbola might do it.

If you bisect the angle at T
and rotate the curve
so T is at the origin
and the bisector
is the x axis,
the equation would be
of the form
$\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}
=1$.

See here for how to get
$a$ and $b$:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola

Then rotate it back
to get the original function.